# How to return three tuples in python involving an if statement

Tags: python, tuples

I am trying to write a program that will print three tuples, but I only succeed in returning only two.

I am suppose to return, in a tuple: The character, the ordinal value, and the the type of the char: "letter", "number" or "punctuation".

I have written the if/elif/else to check for these three values, but don't now how to return them in a tuple, as the third value.

**Here is my code:**

```
def character_info(char):
      ord_value = ord(char)
      ord_result = ord_value
      if char.isdigit():
          "number"
      elif char.isalpha():
          "letter"
      else:
          "punctuation"
      return (char,ord_result)

print character_info("t")
print character_info("3")
print character_info("-")
```

**Practical output:**

```
('t', 116)
('3', 51)
('-', 45)
```

**Expected output**

```
('t', 116, letter)
('3', 51, number)
('-', 45, punctuation)
```

Comment: Inside your `if` statements, capture those strings in a variable, `char_type = "number"` then return it in the tuple `(char, ord_result, char_type)`

Comment: Store the text type is a variable and return it.

Answer (score 4):

If you write a statement like:

```
"number"
```

that is a *no operation*: you simply write a literal, but you do not do anything with that literal at all.

The trick here is to *assign* that literal to a variable that you then can use in your `return` statement. For instance:

```
def character_info(char):
      ord_value = ord(char)
      ord_result = ord_value
      if char.isdigit():
          chartype = "number"
      elif char.isalpha():
          chartype = "letter"
      else:
          chartype = "punctuation"
      return (char,ord_result,chartype)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
def character_info(char):
  ord_value = ord(char)
  ord_result = ord_value
  ord_type = ""
  if char.isdigit():
      ord_type = "number"
  elif char.isalpha():
      ord_type = "letter"
  else:
      ord_type = "punctuation"
  return (char, ord_result, ord_type)

print character_info("t")
print character_info("3")
print character_info("-")
```

You never actually use what you get out of the if statement- I saved it in a variable, then returned it in the end

Answer (score 1):

```
def character_info(char):
   ord_result = ord(char)
   if char.isdigit():
      ord_type = "number"
   elif char.isalpha():
      ord_type = "letter"
   else:
      ord_type = "punctuation"
   return char, ord_result, ord_type


print(character_info("t"))
print(character_info("3"))
print(character_info("-"))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.